# A short question about the "new" cucumber syntax

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, gherkin

Where I found some documentation about the new syntax from cucumber/gherkin?

An example: the old one used to be:

```
"^Some kind of problem ([A-Za-z]+) with (?:a|an) number (\d+)$"
```

The new one:

```
"Some kind of problem {string} with a number {int}"
```

My problem:

How I get this **(?:a|an)** or this **^$** with the new syntax. And where did I find documentation to it?

Thanks and best regards :)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing this.

First as optional part - `Some kind of problem {string} with a(n) number {int}`

Second as alternative - `Some kind of problem {string} with a/an number {int}`

The second one seems to be more suitable to ur needs.

https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#optional-text
https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#alternative-text